# Three.js: Bounding sphere of a scaled object

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, geometry

I have a set of 3D shapes (pyramid, cube, octahedron, prism etc.) and I need to build described sphere around each of them. It is easy to do so using geometry.boundingSphere as it has radius of the described sphere. But if I scale an object the bounding sphere is not being updated. Is it possible to update bounding sphere relatively to the scale?
Using Three.js 0.129.

```
const { position } = entity.object3D;
const mesh = entity.getObject3D('mesh') as THREE.Mesh;

mesh.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();

const { radius } = mesh.geometry.boundingSphere;

createSphere(radius, position);
```

Comment: Try to add that created sphere to an object as its child. So when you scale the object, the sphere will be scaled automatically.

Comment: @prisoner849 that doesn't work for me as I need to be able to add described sphere after scaling the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geometry.boundingSphere` property represents the geometry. You could technically have two meshes with different scales share the same geometry, so you would want to maintain the geometry's original bounding sphere, and then compute a new one for each mesh, individually.

One problem with *scaling* the bounding sphere is that you can scale your mesh in `x`, `y`, and `z` separately, and even invert vertex position values given negative scaling values. unequal scale values would lead to it being less of a sphere, and more of a spheroid, which would not help you in math.

What you *can* do is recompute a bounding sphere for your mesh, given its updated world transformation matrix. I suggest using the world matrix because other ancestors of your mesh could also influence scale in unpredictable ways.

```js
// Given:
// (THREE.Mesh) yourMesh

// Copy the geometry 
let geoClone = yourMesh.geometry.clone() // really bad for memory, but it's simple/easy

// Apply the world transformation to the copy (updates vertex positions)
geoClone.applyMatrix4( yourMesh.matrixWorld )

// Convert the vertices into Vector3s (also bad for memeory)
let vertices = []
let pos = geoClone.attributes.position.array
for( let i = 0, l = pos.length; i < l; i += 3 ){
  vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( pos[i], pos[i+1], pos[i+2] ) )
}

// Create and set your mesh's bounding sphere
yourMesh.userData.boundingSphereWorld = new THREE.Sphere()
yourMesh.userData.boundingSphereWorld.setFromPoints( vertices )
```

This will create a world-aligned bounding sphere for your mesh. If you want one based on local transformations, you can follow the same idea using the local `yourMesh.matrix` matrix instead. Just know that your sphere's center will then be based on your mesh's *local* transformation/rotation, not just its scale.

Comment: thanks for the answer! For some reason `yourMesh.userData.boundingSphereWorld` has `NaN` for radius and center. But `geoClone.boundingSphere` has correct values after applying mesh's matrix, so I used it.

Comment: @Palina That's because I moved a little too quickly. The array passed into `setFromPoints` needs to be an array of `Vector3` objects. I'll update my answer.